# How can I enumerate sockets on a given windows process?

Tags: windows, sockets

I need my program to check if a given Windows process is abusing the network.
I would like to enumerate the process tcp and udp sockets, and see how much data they transferred during a given period.

Is there a C or .Net API that can provide such info?

Comment: Create a sniffer using sharppcap. Set the pcap filters to tcp, udp, and by source address (the source IP address in the IP header to pinpoint only outgoing packets coming from that particular host). Just download the SharpPcap source tree and look at the included examples to see how it's done. For a great resource for pcap filters google "tcpdump(1)" and click the first link.

Answer (score 1):

On Win2k, you can use GetTcpTable(), GetTcp6Table(), GetUdpTable(), and GetUdp6Table() to locate all of the active socket connections.  But to match them to specific process IDs, you would have to manually enumerate the system's open handles looking for TCP/UDP handles, and then query the process information from them.

On XP, you can use AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack() and AllocateAndGetUdpExTableFromStack(), which can return process IDs with each socket connection.

On XP SP2 and later, you can use GetExtendedTcpTable() and GetExtendedUdpTable(), which can return process IDs with each socket connection as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at WinPcap. http://www.winpcap.org/

A C#.net version is available in SharpPcap. http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpPcap.aspx

Comment: The link needs to be updated. Tamirgal's blog is really out of date. A link to the SharpPcap sourceforge project would be much better.