# How to find a list of sockets held by a process in windows?

Tags: windows, sockets

I have a .Net application that maintains a socket pool to reuse them. It is suspected that it might be holding too many of those sockets without releasing them. Is there a way to find the number of socket handles the application is holding to in Windows?

Comment: Related: [How can I enumerate sockets on a given windows process?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1337392/95735)

Comment: In case someone else comes across this question, I tested some software called "SocketSniff at http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/socket_sniffer.html. Not only does it show the sockets, but it also shows the content - worked well, even on 64 bit windows. [Please note: use at own risk; take precautions before running anything downloaded for free on the internet; read the disclaimer on the page etc.]

Answer (score 58):

## Try netstat

Type the type the following from an elevated (admin) command prompt:

**Windows**: `netstat -a -o -n -b`

**Linux**: `netstat -4 -6 -a -n -p`

On Windows, `-b` is to display the executable involved in creating each connection or listening port. See `netstat --help` for a list of all options.

On Linux, `-p` is the equivalent. Type `man netstat` for more information.

**Linux**

Answer (score 18):

## Try tcpview.exe

I like [TCPView from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437).

Good for lots of other things too, but to check your own process out, just find it in the list and look at the sockets it has open, addresses they are bound to, etc.  You can also watch the dynamic pattern of your processes socket usage.