# New to Ruby language and installed Ruby and rails on Windows 8.1 but when rails server it throw following error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.6 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Exiting
G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/
puma/binder.rb:272:in `initialize': Only one usage of each socket address (proto
col/network address/port) is normally permitted. - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 30
00 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pum
a-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:272:in `new'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pum
a-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:272:in `add_tcp_listener'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pum
a-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:105:in `block in parse'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pum
a-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `each'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pum
a-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `parse'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pum
a-3.12.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:151:in `load_and_bind'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pum
a-3.12.0/lib/puma/single.rb:96:in `run'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pum
a-3.12.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:184:in `run'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pum
a-3.12.0/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:70:in `run'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rac
k-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rai
lties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:44:in `start'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rai
lties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform
'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rai
lties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rai
lties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tho
r-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tho
r-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tho
r-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rai
lties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rai
lties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from G:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rai
lties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

but when i run http://localhost:3000 it show This site can’t be reached

Comment: The above error means some other process is running on `port 3000`. Look for the process using `lsof -wni tcp:3000` and kill it `kill -9 <pid>` and then you should be able to run rails server.

Answer (score 0):

Errno::EADDRINUSE says that the socket is already in use. It means that you have started puma already. You need to stop all previous puma instances before starting it again. See

[How to find a list of sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902136/how-to-find-a-list-of-sockets-held-by-a-process-in-windows)

[How to close a tcp port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688949/how-to-close-tcp-and-udp-ports-via-windows-command-line)